# Lucene: How to add a new term to query using a Filter?

Tags: java, search, nlp, lucene

I'm trying to write a Lucene filter which replaces terms like 'what's' with 'what is', 'can't' with 'cannot', etc.

In `incrementToken()` if the term is one of the strings I'm replacing, I calculate a replacement string (e.g what's -> what is) and push it onto the CharTermAttribute:

`termAttr.copyBuffer(replacement.toCharArray, 0, replacement.length)`

But this doesn't seem to be working, when I search for 'what's', i still get results containing 'what's' rather than the string being treated as though it was 'what is'.

What's the right way to accomplish this? Do I need to create a tokenizer? (Ideally I want to keep the StandardTokenizer and add to it rather than replace it)

Comment: I'm not sure how you could reliably replace something such as `he's` - it could be `he has` or `he is` depending on the context ("he's here" vs. "he's got it"). On the other hand, Lucene can augment your indexed terms with synonyms (where `he has` and `he is` are synonyms for `he's`). I have an example of that, if you think it may be useful. But it is not a replacement process - so it may not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved using a tokenizer rather than filter.